# Handling KeyDown Event in a datagridview

Tags: datagridview, keydown

I have made an application in Visual Basic.
It has a Datagridview with data.
Its an unbound datagridview with all columns readonly

When the user click on a row additional data is retrieved from the database and presented on screen.

Now they user wants to scroll through the row with the keyboard.

I wrote an Eventhandler

Private Sub dgVerzamelstaat_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles dgVerzamelstaat.KeyDown

Here i code that the application retrieves the active row with
nIndex = Me.dgVerzamelstaat.CurrentRow.Index

And then runs the same function when then the user clicks a row
But the Active row is not updated in this routine
I think its updated after the code in the event is finished, because i see that the row selection is moved

Is there a way to process the default behaviour before my code executes?

Or is there another reason it doesn't go as planned

Comment: Without some code to go by, speculation and unnecessary questions are bound to follow. Please edit your question to provide more details and the code in question. A full example of what you are trying to achieve would go a long way to help you get a solution. I suggest you peruse SO’s [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you mean by your comment… _”And then runs the same function when then the user clicks a row But the Active row is not updated in this routine I think its updated after the code in the event is finished, because i see that the row selection is moved”_ … ?